# select a line and process its tags on mouse click (python tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hi I’m developing a user interface for processing AI (Adobe illustrator) files, I have grouped sets of lines, using the tag feature.  I want to know which set of lines is selected on click (which tag for example), but I can't figure out how, as the function `click_poligono` always gets the last tag, any help on how I'm supposed to do this??
part of my code is :

```
    def click_poligono(self,event,poligono):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure('poligono%s'%poligono , fill = 'blue')

    def cambio_listbox(self,*args,**kwargs):
        <-------Mysql queries and processes------->
        for i in range(len(matriz_start)):
            print i
            self.canvas.tag_bind('poligono%s'%i , '<ButtonPress-1>' , lambda event: self.click_poligono(event,'%s' % i)

        for j in range(len(matriz_start[i])):
            if True: #if for possible matrix condition
                self.canvas.create_line(10+matriz_start[i][j]['x']*680/maximo,690-(matriz_start[i][j]['y']*680/maximo),10+matriz_end[i][j]['x']*680/maximo,690-(matriz_end[i][j]['y']*680/maximo), width = 2 ,tags ='poligono%s'%i)
```

So the question here is , how can I manage to select the set of lines I click with the mouse , and process it on one function , as the set of lines is variable depending on the number of figures the file (Adobe Illustrator) has..

I hope I'm clear on what I'm asking, and I'm open to new suggestions on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because of lambda.

You have

```
lambda event: self.click_poligono(event,'%s' % i)
```

where `event` is local variable but `i` is not.

Try this

```
lambda event, i=i: self.click_poligono(event,'%s' % i)
```

Comment: how do I mark it as solved?? do I just modify the Title??